# kill process in linux

Tags: linux, c

Суть проблемы такова, что нужно убить процесс по filepath из уровня доступа пользователя, например, из GUI. Подскажите, куда копать....

Comment: [man fuser](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) и не забудьте SEE ALSO там.

Comment: @avp это утилита для терминала.  Меня интересует функция, которую можна заюзать в своем коде...

Comment: *убить процесс по filepath* — расшифруйте, пожалуйста. *из уровня доступа пользователя* — от имени «рядового» пользователя сигнал sigkill может быть передан только тем процессам, владельцем которых является этот пользователь.

Comment: Наиболее подходящей из функций мне представляется popen, т.е. `FILE *in = popen("fuser ...", "r");`. / Но, конечно, посмотрите сорсы fuser и lsof, может там уже есть что-то библиотечное.

Comment: обычный пользователь никогда рутом стать не сможет, единственно возможное решение - запуск отдельного просесса владельцем выполнимого файла которого будет root и будет установлен suid бит в правах доступа. В принципе в suid режиме может быть вся ваша программа, но вы должны быть в этом случае особоенно аккуратны, потому как она все будет выполнять под рутом